# Using productontology.org to add Multiple Types?

Tags: microdata, productontology.org, json-ld

I have recently been reading about [productontology.org](http://www.productontology.org/) to define additional types with schema.org to be more specific.

I am building a website for a local pet store that offers various pet products, grooming and training. I have the following code for the site's schema:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "additionalType": "http://www.productontology.org/id/Dog_grooming",

  //Additional Schema Markup (opening hours, location, etc.)
}
</script>
```

As you can see I added an `additionalType` in the JSON-LD for dog grooming. Can I add multiple `additionalType`s if it applies to the business? IE:

```
"additionalType": "http://www.productontology.org/id/Dog_grooming",
"additionalType": "http://www.productontology.org/id/Dog_training",
```

Or should I stick with one? In other words, is it allowed or beneficial to add more than one `additionalType`?

Also, is my usage of `additionalType` in the JSON-LD correct? (I haven't seen any real examples with `additionalType` and JSON-LD.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `additionalType` in the first snippet is correct.

An example where `additionalType` is used can be seen on Schema.org’s [`IndividualProduct`](http://schema.org/IndividualProduct):

> ```html
> <script type="application/ld+json">
> {
>   "@context": "http://schema.org",
>   "@id": "#product",
>   "@type": "IndividualProduct",
>   "additionalType": "http://www.productontology.org/id/Racing_bicycle",
>   "description": "ACME Racing Bike, bought 8/2008, almost new, with a signature of Eddy Merckx on the frame.",
>   "name": "ACME Racing Bike in black (2008)"
> }
> </script>
> ```

Adding multiple additional types is possible, too. However, not by adding the property multiple times, but, e.g., [by using an array](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#sets-and-lists):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "additionalType": ["http://www.productontology.org/id/Dog_grooming", "http://www.productontology.org/id/Dog_training"]
}
</script>
```

Adding multiple additional types can of course be beneficial: if multiple types apply, so be it! It would make no sense to arbitrarily limit it to one additional type only.
You can, of course, add types from various vocabularies; they don’t have to come from the same vocabulary.