# Multiple addresses in JSON-LD Schema.org

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I have a site I am creating for a non-profit organization. Their organization has a United States Mailing Address and a Canada Mailing Address. I want to add both addresses with Schema.org (using JSON-LD), but I cannot figure out how. I originally tried this:

```
"address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "addressCountry": "United States",
    "addressLocality": "City",
    "addressRegion": "State",
    "postalCode": "12345",
    "postOfficeBoxNumber": "1234"
},
"address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "addressCountry": "Canada",
    "addressLocality": "City",
    "addressRegion": "Province ",
    "postalCode": "Zip",
    "streetAddress": "Box 123 12345 - 123 Street NW"
},
```

When I run a test on this schema it uses only the last address.

I tried wrapping the addresses using `"location": {}` but that threw an error.

How would I add both addresses in the Schema.org markup using JSON-LD?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Similar to [adding multiple string/URL values](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/81081/17633): by [using an **array**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#sets-and-lists).

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "address":
  [
    {
      "@type": "PostalAddress"
    },
    {
      "@type": "PostalAddress"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

Comment: I thought it would be something like this but I couldn't figure it out. Thank you for your help, again.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the same. This looks helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is four years old, but I'm pretty sure there is an even better way to announce multiple addresses under an **@organization**.

Firstly, since Schema.org doesn't have an itemProp specifically for headquarters info, the closest thing is (like described in the above answer) use **address** to add the NAP for the headquarters's location. Then, for the non-HQ location data, use **location** to set up an array mentioning each entry's info.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "address": {HQ PostalAddress, etc.},
  "location":[
    {
      "@type": "PostalAddress"
    },
    {
      "@type": "PostalAddress"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

Now, should the headquarters address be included in the **location** array in addition to being announced separately with the un-nested **address**? It depends: If the HQ is only a corporate office that doesn't handle usual business traffic like the locations do (think about how the Dominoes home office operates versus all the branch/neighborhood locations) I'd say no, otherwise then yes.