# How do I mark up multi product pages with Schema.org and JSON-LD?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I have a client with two products on one page.

However, when I test my mark up, it is only recognising one.

```html
 <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Example Product",
  "image":    "https://www.example.co.uk/~/media/example/product%20images/g/gv15120_h328.png",
  "description": "Vitamins",
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "Client3"
  },
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "4.2",
    "reviewCount": "4842"
},
    "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "priceCurrency": "GBP",
    "price": "11.95",
    "sku": 120
},
    "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "priceCurrency": "GBP",
    "price": "19.95",
    "sku": 240
        }
}
</script>
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple addresses in JSON-LD Schema.org](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81735/multiple-addresses-in-json-ld-schema-org) (while the question is about a different property, the way how to solve it is the same)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean two `Offer` items for one `Product` (like your example suggests).

Instead of repeating the `offers` property, you have to use one `offers` property with an array value (in `[` and `]`):

```json
"offers": 
[
  {
    "@type": "Offer"
  },
  {
    "@type": "Offer"
  }
]
```