# Google SDTT gives error "Missing '}' or object member name." for my JSON-LD

Tags: google-rich-snippets-tool, json-ld

I am guessing Google structured data testing tool behaves strange.

I wrote a code to create JSON-LD for multiple locations for one of my websites. But [Google testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) returns an error:

> Missing '}' or object member name.

The error is related to missing `}`, or `]`, but that's not all right. Because the syntax is correct.

Below is the code I used, maybe others are also in the same condition these days:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "LocalBusiness",
"name": "Company",
"url": "http://www.example.com",
[
{"address": {
    "addressLocality": "United Arab Emirates",
    "addressRegion": "Dubai",
    "streetAddress": "Building 213",
        "telephone" : "04 444 5555"
     "openingHours": ["Su, Mo,Tu,We,Th, 09:00-18:00"],
    },

{"address": {
    "addressLocality": "Jordan",
    "addressRegion": "Amman",
    "postalCode":"XXXXXXX",
    "streetAddress": "Building 213"
     "openingHours": ["Su, Mo,Tu,We,Th, 09:00-18:00"],
    },



{"address": {
    "addressLocality": "Lebanon",
    "addressRegion": "Beirut",
    "streetAddress": "Building 213",
    "telephone" : "+961 444 5555"
     "openingHours": ["Su, Mo,Tu,We,Th, 09:00-18:00"],
    },


{"address": {
    "addressLocality": "Qatar",
    "addressRegion": "Doha",
    "streetAddress": "Building 213",
    "telephone" : "+1(503) 444 5555"
     "openingHours": ["Su, Mo,Tu,We,Th, 09:00-18:00"],
    },

{"address": {
    "addressLocality": "Saudi Arabia",
    "addressRegion": "Riyadh",
    "streetAddress": "Building 213",
        "telephone" : "+966 1 4444 5555"
     "openingHours": ["Su, Mo,Tu,We,Th, 09:00-18:00"],

    },

{"address": {
    "addressLocality": "Egypt",
    "addressRegion": "New Cairo",
    "streetAddress": "Building 213",
        "telephone" : "+20 2 44445555"
     "openingHours": ["Su, Mo,Tu,We,Th, 09:00-18:00"],

    }
],

"description": "Company description",
"email":"support@example.com",
"logo": "http://www.example.com/w-logo.png",
"sameAs" : [ "https://www.facebook.com/Example",
"https://twitter.com/Example",
"https://plus.google.com/+Example",
"https://www.youtube.com/user/Example",
"http://www.slideshare.net/Example",
"https://www.linkedin.com/company/Example"]
}
</script>
```

Comment: "the syntax is correct." - I'm curious why/how you think the syntax is correct - did you use a validator; which one? (Because the syntax is obviously not correct?)

Comment: As DocRoot suggests, running your JSON through a [validator](http://jsonlint.com/) or [parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) will show you a number of errors with it. One simple quick test you can perform is to count the number of opening `{` and closing `}` braces - you have 13 opening but only 7 closing - they should be equal.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to provide multiple addresses, you have to specify [one `address` property with an array value](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/81745/17633), not an array of `address` properties.

If you click at the error in the SDTT, the tool correctly highlights the line where the error begins (line 7, i.e., the opening `[`).

Comment: There would seem to be some more errors as well... missing commas after several property values and erroneous commas after the last property (as if it's been manually edited?).