# How to write JSON-LD for list of people?

Tags: html, schema.org, json-ld

I have a page that contains a list of people with a link of each that will open the main page of that person.

Each link should have its own structured data.

I'm using JSON-LD, but the [example given is in Microdata format](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#schemaorg_expected). So to write it in JSON-LD format, should I write the complete scripts for each URL?

The script for one URL is

```html
  <script type="application/ld+json">
  {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Person",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "addressLocality": "Seattle",
    "addressRegion": "WA",
    "postalCode": "98052",
    "streetAddress": "20341 Whitworth Institute 405 N. Whitworth"
  },
  "colleague": [
    "http://www.xyz.edu/students/alicejones.html",
    "http://www.xyz.edu/students/bobsmith.html"
  ],
  "email": "mailto:jane-doe@xyz.edu",
  "image": "janedoe.jpg",
  "jobTitle": "Professor",
  "name": "Jane Doe",
  "telephone": "(425) 123-4567",
  "url": "http://www.janedoe.com"
}
</script>
```

Let's say I have a list of 15 persons on one page. Should I write these 15 scripts separately or there's some other way to write JSON-LD in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options:

- as top-level items
  (only use this if the other two options are not possible)
- as values for a property
  (best option, but requires that Schema.org offers a suitable type/property for your case)
- as `ItemList`
  (second-best option; requires that it makes sense to group them)

#### As top-level items

If you want to provide the `Person` items as top-level items (i.e., not nested as values for a property of some other type), you can [either use multiple `script` elements, or one `script` element with `@graph`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33457312/1591669):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Person"
}
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Person"
}
</script>
```

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@graph": 
  [
    {
       "@type": "Person"
    },
    {
       "@type": "Person"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

#### As values for a property

If you want to provide the `Person` items as values for a property of some other type, use [an array as value](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/81745/17633).

Example case: You could have an [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) and want to reference the employed `Person`s with the [`employee`](http://schema.org/employee) property:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "employee":
  [
    {
      "@type": "Person"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

#### As list

If you want to provide the `Person` items as list, you can use the [`ItemList` type](http://schema.org/ItemList).

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "ItemList",
  "itemListElement": [
    {
      "@type": "Person"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking for.
I prefer the second best option.

Comment: the `ItemList` option did the trick for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a property **[BreadcrumbList](http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList)** for your list. Something like this:

```json
{
 "@context": "http://schema.org",
 "@type": "BreadcrumbList", 
 "name": "Name of the list",
 "description": "Description of the list",
 "itemListElement":
 [
  {
   "@type": "ListItem",
   "position": 1,
   "item":
   {
    "@type": "Person",
    "@id": "https://example.com/person1",
    "name": "name of person1"
    }
  },
  {
   "@type": "ListItem",
  "position": 2,
  "item":
   {
     "@type": "Person",
    "@id": "https://example.com/person2",
     "name": "name of person2"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: A list of persons (e.g., on a team page), is not a breadcrumb list. Breadcrumbs are a type of navigation that either shows the parent pages of the current page, or the pages that were visited before.

Comment: Right, I was going to comment the same thing.

Comment: @unor, at what page we use `BreadcrumbList`.
Like, I have a link at home page to go to a page (say the category list) that contains **employees List**, **machines List**, **project list** as links of their list on some page (say the main list). Like **employees list** contains the list of all employees. And further, each employee is a link to the employee's profile on some page (say final page).
So among these pages, which page is going to have json-ld script for BreadcrumbList ?

Comment: @Siraj: I think this should be a separate question, the comments are not the right place for it.

Comment: @unor, description of BreadcrumbList: "A BreadcrumbList is an ItemList consisting of a chain of linked Web pages, typically described using at least their URL and their name...". In your question, you are asking how to partition structured data for a list with URL. My answer for this.

Comment: The description of `BreadcrumbList` is not really good for authors that don’t know what a breadcrumb navigation is (see the Wikipedia article [*Breadcrumb*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_(navigation))). Important is the term "chain". In this context, you would have a chain if the pages are organized in a hierarchy, or if you show the history of visited pages. -- Your snippet would be correct if you use `ItemList` (which is the parent type) instead of `BreadcrumbList`.