# Schema.org and multiple products on a page

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I have a photography business that offers multiple services. Our site is hosted with Zenfolio. They allow me to create custom web pages that contain HTML and CSS as expected.

One of our services pages is Maternity & Newborn. We offer several packages. As of right now, I don't have any schema.org data on that page, Google Webmaster Tools shows that I have 
structured data and is showing one price- not sure where they are getting that from.

How can I add multiple products and prices using the schema?

Here's what I'm using on another page that offers just one product:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Name here",
  "image": "p2222510803-3.jpg",
  "description": "Desc",
  "sku": "skuhere",
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "Product1"
  },
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "4.9",
    "reviewCount": "17"
  },
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "priceCurrency": "USD",
    "price": "250.00",
    "priceValidUntil": "2020-01-01",
    "itemCondition": "https://schema.org/NewCondition",
    "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
    "seller": {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "name": "CompName"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: [Does this question help?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/110177/17633)

Comment: At a guess it sounds like your talking about a Service with multiple Offers that each relate to a package.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a Service with an OfferCatalog. Here is an example of how to get started, lifted [directly from Schema.org](https://schema.org/Service) under CC-BY-SA:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Service",
  "serviceType": "Weekly home cleaning",
  "provider": {
    "@type": "LocalBusiness",
    "name": "ACME Home Cleaning"
  },
  "areaServed": {
    "@type": "State",
    "name": "Massachusetts"
  },
  "hasOfferCatalog": {
    "@type": "OfferCatalog",
    "name": "Cleaning services",
    "itemListElement": [
      {
        "@type": "OfferCatalog",
        "name": "House Cleaning",
        "itemListElement": [
          {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "itemOffered": {
              "@type": "Service",
              "name": "Apartment light cleaning"
            }
          },
          {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "itemOffered": {
              "@type": "Service",
              "name": "House light cleaning up to 2 bedrooms"
            }
          },
          {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "itemOffered": {
              "@type": "Service",
              "name": "House light cleaning 3+ bedrooms"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@type": "OfferCatalog",
        "name": "One-time services",
        "itemListElement": [
          {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "itemOffered": {
              "@type": "Service",
              "name": "Window washing"
            }
          },
          {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "itemOffered": {
              "@type": "Service",
              "name": "Carpet cleaning"
            }
          },
          {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "itemOffered": {
              "@type": "Service",
              "name": "Move in/out cleaning"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can markup your services as a product.

Two reasons to do this

1. Google doesn’t support “service” markup
2. Services are included in Product’s definition in [schema.org](https://schema.org/Product)

If you have multiple different services on a single page, then markup them one by one - individually.

If you have same services but with vivid options and price packages then use aggregate product markup.

Read about [Google’s structured data product markup here.](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product) You will get the sample code, which you can modify as per the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You use the schema to describe the meaning of a single page. When they click on a particular product to go to its page, that's when you add a schema for that particular product.

More info: https://schema.org/docs/gs.html

Comment: Hi, what I have a page that describes a service and that particular service has multiple packages. I want to specify those if possible...