# Tagging multiple Trip schema on one page

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I can get a single `Trip` marked up correctly using Schema.org:

```json
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Trip",
    "name": "Your ideal trip to England",
    "description": "The dozen best places and areas that should be on you list when visiting England.  Choose you own order but visit as many as you can",
    "itinerary": [
        {
            "@type": "City",
            "name": "Poole",
            "description":  "Sail from Poole to Jersey onboard Condor Liberation in as little as 4 hours 30 minutes",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poole"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Country",
            "name": "Jersey",
            "description": "Sail to Jersey and fall in love with luscious landsapes and stunning skies",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jersey"
        },
    ]
}
```

But when I add another `Trip`, I get the errors:

```json
    {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Trip",
    "name": "Your ideal trip to England",
    "description": "The dozen best places and areas that should be on you list when visiting England.  Choose you own order but visit as many as you can",
    "itinerary": [
        {
            "@type": "City",
            "name": "Poole",
            "description":  "Sail from Poole to Jersey onboard Condor Liberation in as little as 4 hours 30 minutes",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poole"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Country",
            "name": "Jersey",
            "description": "Sail to Jersey and fall in love with luscious landsapes and stunning skies",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jersey"
        },
    ]
    },
    {"@type": "Trip",
    "name": "Your ideal trip to England",
    "description": "The dozen best places and areas that should be on you list when visiting England.  Choose you own order but visit as many as you can",
    "itinerary": [
        {
            "@type": "City",
            "name": "Poole",
            "description":  "Sail from Poole to Jersey onboard Condor Liberation in as little as 4 hours 30 minutes",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poole"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Country",
            "name": "Jersey",
            "description": "Sail to Jersey and fall in love with luscious landsapes and stunning skies",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jersey"
        }
    ]
}
```

I basically need to add, Poole to Jersey, Portsmouth to Jersey, St Malo to Jersey as separate `Trip`s, not part of the same `itinerary`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct, by Google Structured Data Testing Tool successfully validated code for multiple Trip entities (an array of) would be:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{  
   "@context":"http://schema.org",
   "@graph":[  
      {  
         "@type":"Trip",
         "name":"Your ideal trip to England",
         "description":"The dozen best places and areas that should be on you list when visiting England.  Choose you own order but visit as many as you can",
         "itinerary":[  
            {  
               "@type":"City",
               "name":"Poole",
               "description":"Sail from Poole to Jersey onboard Condor Liberation in as little as 4 hours 30 minutes",
               "url":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poole"
            },
            {  
               "@type":"Country",
               "name":"Jersey",
               "description":"Sail to Jersey and fall in love with luscious landsapes and stunning skies",
               "url":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jersey"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "@type":"Trip",
         "name":"Your ideal trip to France",
         "description":"The dozen best places and areas that should be on you list when visiting France.  Choose you own order but visit as many as you can",
         "itinerary":[  
            {  
               "@type":"City",
               "name":"Paris",
               "description":"Travel to Paris onboard Condor Liberation in as little as 4 hours 30 minutes",
               "url":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris"
            },
            {  
               "@type":"Country",
               "name":"France",
               "description":"Travel to Paris and fall in love with luscious landsapes and stunning skies",
               "url":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
</script>
```

**Note**, thate `itinerary` is a *pending* property, currently not included into the regular draft.

Comment: Ohh ok thank you - what had I done wrong?

Comment: was it this at the end      ]
}
]
}

Comment: @Becky: Note the `@graph` in line 4. You are correctly using an array for the `itinerary` values, but with top-level items, this doesn’t work (as there is no property they are added to), so you either have to use `@graph` with an array value, or use multiple `script` elements. ([Details](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/110184/17633))

Comment: I just improved the indentation so that the ending brackets are less ambiguous.

Comment: Ohh I see - thank  you very much for the explanation this is really helpful!