# How to structure an array of entries in schema.org/JSON-LD?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I'm implementing schemas for financial information (using JSON-LD), in this case mortgage loans.

The example on the bottom of the documentation site https://schema.org/MortgageLoan shows how to implement this for a specific loan, however I'm not quite sure of how to modify the graph when I have several mortgage loans, each with a different `loanTerm` and `interestRate`. Should I just repeat this whole block for each loan? Or can I nest each mortgage loan under this `@type` somehow?

The information I want to convey is that a loan can have different loan terms, which will have different interest rates.

I could put the different rates and terms as nested objects under each label, but then there is seems to be no relation between the two.

How should I do this? This is some example code of what I have.

```json
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "MortgageLoan",
    "name": "A name of this loan...",
    "loanType": "A type of loan...",
    "description": "A description...",
    "interestRate": [
        {
        "@type":"QuantitativeValue",
        "name":"Rate",
        "value": "3",
        "unitCode": "P1"
        }
    ],
    "loanTerm": {
        "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
        "name": "Binding period",
        "value": 12,
        "uniTtext": "months"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide multiple `MortgageLoan` items.

**Why?** Even if multiple [`interestRate`](https://schema.org/interestRate) values would represent alternatives (which, probably, isn’t the case), there is no way to convey which `interestRate` value belongs to which [`loanTerm`](https://schema.org/loanTerm) value. So, multiple `interestRate` and `loanTerm` values would *all* apply.

**How to provide multiple `MortgageLoan` items?** You can either provide one `script` element per `MortgageLoan` item, or you can have one `script` element with `@graph` that lists all `MortgageLoan` items ([see the two examples in the section "As top-level items"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/110184/17633)).

Comment: Yes that is exactly the problem I was thinking about, there is no relation between the interestRate and the loanTerm if you don't provide multiple items somehow.

I will do as you suggest, thanks a lot!